# Isogenies and dimensions

Tags: lie-groups, compact-manifolds, complex-manifolds

Let $f: \mathbb{C}^g/L\to\mathbb{C}^{g'}/L'$ be an isogeny of complex tori, i.e. a surjective Lie group morphism with finite kernel.

Is it obvious that $g\ge g'$ ?

It is easy to show that $f$ is induced by a linear map $\mathbb{C}^g\to\mathbb{C}^{g'}$ that is injective, but I cannot see why this map should be an isomorphism. A surjective morphism of Lie group is not necessarily a submersion, right ?

Comment: Do you mean the linear map $\mathbb C^g \to \mathbb C^{g'}$ is surjective?

Comment: Or is your question if $g = g'$?

Comment: $g=g'$, $g\ge g'$ or the linear map is surjective are equivalent, since it is injective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, any Lie group homomorphism whose kernel is a discrete subgroup of the center is a normal covering.  In particular it is a local isomorphism so in your case $g = g'$.  For a proof, see proposition 1.19 of http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wziller/math650/LieGroupsReps.pdf.

Comment: Thank you! But it seems a bit involved (the hypothesis being way more general than what we need). I wonder if there is a simpler argument.